# Combining two Access Queries

Tags: ms-access

I three tables.  Table1, Table2, Table3.  They all have a field called KB. Can I have one query to accomplish:  Get all the information from table2, when Table1 KB = Table2 KB But only if table1 KB doesn't exist in Table3. I currently have 2 Queries. One to determine which KBs in Table1 don't exist in Table3. I then run a query against those results showing me all the records in Table2 that have matching KB.  Can I do that all in 1 query, or 2 queries the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 AS t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS t1 WHERE t1.KB = t2.KB)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table3 AS t3 WHERE t3.KB = t2.KB)
```

or with an `INNER` join of `table2` to `table1` and a `LEFT` join of `table2` to `table1` from which you will return only the non matching rows:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (table2 AS t2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON t2.KB = Table1.KB) 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON t2.KB = table3.KB
WHERE table3.KB IS NULL
```

This may return duplicate rows of `table2` if the relationship of table2 and table1 is `1:n`, so in this case you can use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.*
....................
```